# Unable to start SonarQube with version 6.7

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I have installed sonar 6.7 and when i try to start it i am getting error related to elasticsearch.

> Error: exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xace7a72b,
>   L:/127.0.0.1:36352 - R:/127.0.0.1:9200]], closing connection
>   java.io.IOException: Invalid string; unexpected character: 180 hex:
>   b4.

But it is working with old sonar version 6.0

I have checked that elasticsearch is listening on localhost 9200 port.
Anyone can help please reply.

Comment: More logs could help

Answer (score 1):

Check the other applications are using elastic search port.

make the port as 0 it will automatically take free port in sonar.properties and restart.

Elasticsearch port. Default is 9001. Use 0 to get a free port.
 As a security precaution, should be blocked by a firewall and not exposed to the Internet.

sonar.search.port=0